# windows 7 splitting up a pdf file

Tags: windows-7, windows

how do you split up a pdf file in windows?  when I got to print option and choose the pages that I want to separate(its a 346 page doc and I only need 25 pages), there is not option to pdf those pages.

Comment: please take an effort to search google before asking such a simple task. There are plenty of PDF to WORD converters. convert to word and edit as needed.

Answer (score 1):

There's software for that, for example the free PDFsam:
http://www.pdfsam.org